# How to make my react-native android app appear in the share list of another android app

Tags: android, react-native

Here, I am adding the image for more clarification of my problem statement.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're looking to create a *share activity* for your Android app.

[react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension) should provide you with a good starting point (as well as providing support for iOS if you're working on a Mac).

Comment: Thanks, app is now getting displayed within share list, but still I am not getting any leads to handle content to be shared within app and how to display that content placed within particular screen/page